# VBScript Regular Expression to find domain name from a line of strings

Tags: regex, vbscript

I am trying to create a regular expression to find a domain name inside a line.

Currently, I tried this, but not working.

```
Set objDomainEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
objDomainEx.Global = True   
objDomainEx.Pattern = "((?:[A-Z0-9-]+\.)+[A-Z]{2,4})$"
Set matches = objDomainEx.Execute(strSearchString) 
If matches.Count > 0 Then
    For Each strMatch in matches    
       Wscript.Echo strMatch.Value
    Next
End If
```

Whats wrong with this. My domain name looks like [www.]aaaaa.sssss.vvvvv.domain or something like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your character class doesn't include lowercase letters. You should include `[a-z]` as well.

```
((?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,4})$
```

Alternatively, you can make your Regex object case-insensitive as

```
objDomainEx.IgnoreCase = True
```

Answer (score 0):

```
objDomainEx.Pattern = "((?:[A-Z0-9-]+\.)+[A-Z]{2,4})$"
```

> My domain name looks like [www.]aaaaa.sssss.vvvvv.domain

So the problems here are:

1. your regex appears to only match upper case letters.
2. your regex assumes that the final part of the domain will only be up to 4 characters long. (there are domains with longer suffixes than this).